# MouseListener position on large frame Java

Tags: java, coordinates

The MouseListeners getX() and getY() returns the position of the mouse cursor but since I have a very large image in a `scrollpane` I only get the position of the currently visible parts of the image. Is there anyway to get the pixel coordinate of the image?
Here is the current code:

```
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(Image)));
scrollPane.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        mx1 = e.getX();
        my1 = e.getY();
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        mx2 = e.getX();
        my2 = e.getY();
    }
}
```

Comment: Try adding the mouse listener to the JLabel instead of the JScrollPane.

Comment: Thank you, this worked great exept that since the window is resizeable the lable can get larger than the image in it but I think I can handle that on my own. @SteveChaloner

Answer (score 0):

You can get access to the visible in `JScrollPane` part via `scrollPane.getViewport().getViewRect()`. It returns a `Rectangle` object, where you can find the location of visible part of scroll and its size.

In your case, as was mentioned, you just need to add listener to the label itself.

Answer (score 0):

Use AdjustmentListener for this. Check the method `addAdjustmentListener` from `JScrollBar` [in the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollBar.html#addAdjustmentListener%28java.awt.event.AdjustmentListener%29)